# How can I get simple response from node.js server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

I am trying to learn Node.js (creating REST API and sending message from server). So I have an issue about sending response from server to client side. When I am logging the request from server side I see the request but I am not able to send message to client side.

My Node.js server:

```
//handle a user request
function onRequest(request, response){
    if(request.method =='GET' && request.url=='/'){
        response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type":"text/html"});
        fs.createReadStream("./index.html").pipe(response);
        console.log(request.url);
    }
    else if(request.method =='GET' && request.url=='/try'){
     console.log("I am getting the request");
     response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type":"text/plain","Access-Control-Allow Origin":"*"});

        response.write("test message");
        response.end();
    }
    else{
        console.log(request.url);
        send404Response(response);
    }

}

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);
```

My client side function:

```
function sendRequest(){

        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhttp.onreadystatechange==4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
            alert("test alert") ;
            }
        }
        xhttp.open("GET", "http://127.0.0.1:8888/try", true);
        xhttp.send();

        }
```

Any help is appreciated... thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried changing the client code to 'alert'  on all conditions, not just for status 200 ? Also if you're running the client from a browser it might help to see the console log (as in F12 on chrome) .

Comment: Updated the question with chrome console result

Comment: Updated the question for current state... I do not get anything on chrome console and I do not get alert either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by changing the if statement from:

```
if (xhttp.onreadystatechange==4 && xhttp.status == 200)
```

To:

```
if (xhttp.readyState==4 && xhttp.status == 200)
```

Comment: While trying to code in vanilla Javascript is interesting (started that way myself), I would suggest you take a look at some libraries which make it much much more easy to do http requests. Client side you might want to use JQuery, server side you might want to use the request module for nodejs. Both lead to way more simple http requests than vanilla Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' to your response header:

Here is a link which explains CORS:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Comment: I've tried that but it creates another error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Comment: updated the question... I do not get any error now about that but I do not get alert either

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the update. You seem to have run into the notorious issue of **cross domain requests**... it's a security issue, roughly speaking browsers won't allow a page loaded from one site to issue ajax requests into another site.

In other words, **it matters how your browser opened that html which issues the ajax request**. It should be ok if the page itself was obtained , say, through 'http://127.0.0.1:8888/index.html' (where index.html has some button or whatever that issues the ajax). 
If your final intention is indeed to deploy the static page on the same server+port that makes the dynamic replies, you're fine. If you meant for them to be deployed on different machines/ports, you'll probably need to look into CORS...

Comment: My intention is to create static page on localhost:8888/ that makes the dynamic replies... But after adding 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header to my response. I get net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET error

Comment: Just to clarify - did you actually follow that intention, and made sure the browser opens your page through http://127.0.0.1 (not "localhost" because that doesn't match your xhttp.open code)? If so, you shouldn't need that 'allow origin'. Allow origin is for cross-domain (=if you open your page differently), and if you want cross-domain then it might require some proper 3rd party implementation, it sometimes amounts to more than just a header (e.g. 'preflight' negotiation)

Comment: yes you are right...While debugging I realized that if I use 127.0.0.1 there is no need to add 'access-control-allow-origin' header. Btw the problem was about the if statement. I have added an answer